# How can I create HTML column headings like this?

Tags: html, html-table

HTML Table I want to create

[image]

My only problem is how do I get the column headings for Monday Tuesday etc. like that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">

td { 
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" >
 <caption style="text-align:right;" align="bottom" >Printable Calender January 2017 available from www.getmeacalender.com</captio>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="center"  valign="middle"  style="font-weight:bold; font-size:70pt; ">January</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">1</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">2</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">3</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">4</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">5</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">6</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">7</td>  

 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">8</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">9</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">10</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">11</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">12</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">13</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">14</td>  

 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">15</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">16</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">17</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">18</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">19</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">20</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">21</td>  

 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">22</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">23</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">24</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">25</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">26</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">27</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">28</td>
    

 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td align="left" valign="top">29</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">30</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top">31</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="4">Notes:</td>  

 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</caption>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the topmost headings, ie, for Sunday Monday etc.

I couldn't add them directly to my table since there is no border around them.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Provide code that you tried.

Comment: I can but the site is not letting me

Comment: First problem: your question looks a lot like a homework
Second problem: Just indent the code part of your question with four spaces so that it shows in a code box next time.

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to hide the border:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: thin solid;
}

.noBorder td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="noBorder">
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: sorry, just saw the image, this code will do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

td { 
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.header td {
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
}

table {
    border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" >
    <caption style="text-align:right;" align="bottom" >Printable Calender January 2017 available from www.getmeacalender.com</captio>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
        <td align="left" valign="top">Sun</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Mon</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Tue</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Wed</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Thu</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Fri</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Sat</td>        

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"  valign="middle"  style="font-weight:bold; font-size:70pt; ">January</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">1</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">2</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">3</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">4</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">5</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">6</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">7</td>        

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">8</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">9</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">10</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">11</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">12</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">13</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">14</td>       

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">15</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">16</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">17</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">18</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">19</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">20</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">21</td>       

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">22</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">23</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">24</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">25</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">26</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">27</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">28</td>


    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">29</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">30</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">31</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="4">Notes:</td>       

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</caption>
</body>
</html>
```